# How can i send a dm on instagram via private api?

Tags: python, testing, instagram, instagram-api

I want to send via python an instagram DM with the private api

I tried this:

```py
def send_dm(session, id, message):
    response = session.post(f"https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/direct_v2/threads/broadcast/text/", data={
        'recipient_users': f'["{id}"]',
        'text': message
    })
    return json.loads(response.text)
```

Comment: You should expand your question, saying what happens when you try the code you show. There also seems to be code missing. You define a function, but in the snippet you shared, it isn't run anywhere.